# It keeps outputing error: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-connector-python

```
def getLevels(userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus):
try:
  statement = "SELECT userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus FROM levels WHERE userName=%s AND levelID=%s AND levelName=%s AND coins=%s AND amognus=%0s AND NOT starStars=%0s"
  data = (userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus,)
  cursor.execute(statement, data)
  for (userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars) in cursor:
    print(f"Got records of level {userName}, {levelID}, {levelLength}, {coins}, {starStars}")
except database.Error as e:
  print(f"Error retrieving entry from database: {e}")
```

getLevels("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")

Comment: you passing 6x params instead of 7, already missed 1 more parameter. you missed 'levelLength' in your where clause

Comment: it still doesnt work

Comment: statement = "SELECT userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus FROM levels WHERE userName=%s AND levelID=%s AND levelName=%s AND levelLength =%s AND coins=%s AND amognus=%0s AND NOT starStars=%0s"

Comment: remove 0 from %0s

Comment: i want to filter the values of amognus that is 0 and starStars that isnt 0

Comment: and if i do that it wont output anything

Comment: you have two way first stop using dynamic value(NOT startStars=0) or use %s and pass 0 values to those cols

Comment: how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
def getLevels(userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars=0, amognus=0):
    try:
        statement = "SELECT userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus FROM levels WHERE userName=%s AND levelID=%s AND levelName=%s AND levelLength=%s AND coins=%s AND NOT starStars=%s AND amognus=%s"
        data = (userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars, amognus,)
        cursor.execute(statement, data)
        for (userName, levelID, levelName, levelLength, coins, starStars) in cursor:
            print(f"Got records of level {userName}, {levelID}, {levelLength}, {coins}, {starStars}")
    except database.Error as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving entry from database: {e}")
```

if you not passing dynamic params to startStart and amognus from your function those fill dynamicly as params 0.

```
getLevels("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")
```

to

```
getLevels(userName='coin_', levelID=1, levelName=1, levelLength=1, coins=...., starStars, amognus)
```

Comment: implementing the fix
```PS D:\New folder\wgdps bot> py db.py
  File "D:\New folder\wgdps bot\db.py", line 25
    getLevels(userName='coin_', levelID=1, levelName=1, levelLength=1, coins=1, starStars, amognus)
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument```                                      

setting starstars as 1 and amognus as 0
```PS D:\New folder\wgdps bot> py db.py
connicted :lol:
PS D:\New folder\wgdps bot>```

Comment: change positional args ( already edited) , make sure your arguments follows exactly keywords positions

Comment: wdym? i already made sure that it follows the pos listed above

Comment: is there a limit of the amount of data it could output?